# How to avoid NGEN?

Tags: c#, .net, certificate, ngen

My application requires my to sign all referenced .dlls with a certificate. Unfortunately, .dlls like System.dll are being compiled as native images and I'm unable to sign them. Is there a way to disable NGEN and use local versions of these .dlls which I can sign?

Comment: You should not need to sign .NET framework assemblies.

Comment: In this case, they need to be. Is there a way to disable NGEN?